# remove del tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: parsing, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a little stupid problem with BeautifulSoup and Python3. This is my HTML :

```
<span id="gaixm--1521602--15686128--ADHP.GEO_LONG" Visibility="None">
        <del class="cellChanged NO_REVISION_MARK AmdtDeletedAIRAC" title="Date d'entrée en vigueur: 17 SEP 2015. " id="geaip_4b6c6e3f-9841-400c-9359-6ae9b334448d">001°49'57"E</del>
        <ins class="cellChanged AmdtInsertedAIRAC" title="Date d'entrée en vigueur: 17 SEP 2015. " id="geaip_311221e8-2de7-4fce-b261-e0e9fb988238">001°49'52"E</ins>
</span>
```

I want to remove all the del tag. But when I do :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
soup.del.decompose()
tbody_tag = soup.table.tbody
print(tbody_tag)
```

I have an error (and it's normal, del it's a python name..) :

```
  File "algo.py", line 52
    soup.del.decompose()
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
```

So... How can I do this ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use findAll function and then delete all results

```
for d in soup.findAll('del'):
  d.decompose()
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! BeautifulSoup doesn't define a class for del tag ?

Comment: Not sure. I'd prefer use lxml)

Comment: Why ? (Sorry for the questions! :p)

Comment: it's much faster than beautifulsoup